# Building a computer for the first time from scratch - will this really work?

Tags: computer-building

I'm building [my own computer](http://nike1.se/c/index.txt), and I just finished picking out all of my parts. Now I just want to be sure it'll all work before I order it. I'm mean specifically if the RAM & Graphic card will fit on the motherboard I chose.

These are the parts:

- Motherboard: Asus P5KPL Socket 775 - DDR2 / PCI-E / SATA

[image]

- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 2,93GHz / 3MB / 1066MHz Socket 775
- GPU: Asus ATI Radeon HD 4650
- RAM: Kingston HyperX 2048MB DDR2 PC2-8500 1066MHz (KHX8500D2K2/2G) (2x1024MB)
- Harddrive: Seagate Momentus 5400.6 250GB SATA 2.5"
- Chassis & PSU: Ace Clubs 2 - Svart (500 Watt)
- DVD-drive: Samsung Intern SATA DVD±RW 22x

So have I picked the right parts and how will I know what will be compatible in the future?

Comment: suggestion: instead of linking to an offsite parts list, *list them in your post*.

Comment: I did that at first but i'm not allowed to post more than one link, so i can't link to the website.

Comment: if you list the individual parts (eg with model #s) you don't need an external link.  also, you can add additional URLs in comments.

Comment: Alright, i'll do that next time. :)

Comment: There! I tried fixing your question, though I generally dislike questions that are so localised and would rather "teach" people how to find out if computer parts are compatible or give them a site that checks it for them!

Comment: In general it is also helpful to indicate the use of the system, is this a general purpose computer, a CAD workstation, a development machine?  Might help people not only tell you if the parts are compatible but also going to perform for your application.

Answer (score 8):

You've also selected a 2.5" hard drive, which is a laptop hard drive.  The drive won't mount correctly in a desktop case without an adapter (although the cabling will work).  Desktop drives are 3.5".

Also a 3.5" desktop hard drive will be faster and most likely be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you think this one would be OK?

http://www.webhallen.com/prod.php?id=66905

Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes that drive will work. Really any 3.5" SATA drive is going to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Hey, I don't speak swedish, but the parts look compatible with one another.

There is a problem, though.

The case is **microATX** while the mother board is an **ATX** motherboard. Ie: **The motherboard will not fit in [the case](http://www.aceofsweden.com/catalog/product/view/id/6/s/clubs2/category/3/)!**

maybe you could go for the [Heros4](http://www.webhallen.com/prod.php?id=95421) instead, which comes with 500W PSU, is the same price, and takes ATX motherboards?

Comment: Thanks for your advice brice. :) That sounds like a pretty logical idea, i changed it ^^

Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Unless you have need of full ATX for the extra PCIe slots or particular features of that board, I'd be more tempted to go for a microATX motherboard eg the "Asus - Socket 775 - uATX Intel G31 (P5KPL-AM/PS)" listed on that site. 

Also given that it's a test machine, I'd go for the E5300 CPU as it is substantially cheaper whilst still being a very capable processor, and ideal for experimenting with overclocking.

Comment: Are you referring to this motherboard? http://www.webhallen.com/prod.php?id=104733 Unfortunately, it says it's only a demo and no cables and accessories are included. Also, there guaranty is much shorter on demo products. I think i'll stay with the CPU i chose though.